# Not able to decode unicode of Currency Symbol when passed as environment variables

Tags: java, unicode

The following code works well for Rupee Symbol.

```
String encode ="\u20B9";
byte[] ptext = encode.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String value = new String(ptext,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.print(value);

It prints : ₹
```

But when we pass Rupee Symbol unicode as Environment variable it's not working

```
String encode = System.getenv("encode");
byte[] ptext = encode.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String value = new String(ptext,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.print(value);

It prints : \u20B9
```

This i have tried on mac OS.

Comment: What is the host OS?

Comment: Add details as edits to your Question rather than as comments.

Comment: what happens when you print the value without going through the useless decode/encode steps?

Comment: String encode = System.getenv("encode"); It prints : \u20B9

Comment: That means the value of the environment variable is literally `"\\u20B9"` (where `"\\"` is a single `'\'` in memory). You would have to strip off the leading `"\\u"`, parse just the `"20B9"` into an `int` using `Integer.parseInt("20B9", 16)`, and then cast the `int` to a `char`, which you can then put into a `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java only understands `\uXXXX` format when it's inside a Java source file and the compiler handles it (parses it and converts it to a single character). If you read the value from somewhere, it won't be interpreted as a unicode character (except in a .properties file, which is a bit special).

Answer (score 0):

## Copy-Paste `₹` character

Paste the actual `₹` character rather than using the `\u` escape, as noted in [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51954563/642706) by Kayaman.

Works on [macOS High Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) with [Java 10.0.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10) ([Zulu](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-and-zulu-enterprise/) by [Azul Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems)) within [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2018.2.2.

[image]

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

public class Env {
    // Example passing Unicode characters via system environment variable.
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Bonjour tout le monde." );
        System.out.println( System.getProperty( "java.version" ) );
        System.out.println( System.getenv( "wazzup" ) );
        System.out.println( System.getenv( "fire" ) );
        System.out.println( System.getenv( "rupee" ) );
    }
}
```

> Bonjour tout le monde.
>
> 10.0.1
>
> lunch
>
> ₹

## UnicodeChecker app

[image]

Tip: You can find and copy all the Unicode characters from within the excellent free-of-cost macOS app, [UnicodeChecker](https://earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/index.html).